# what does this mean in Java?

Tags: java, loops, foreach

What does the following code do in Java:

```
for(JCheckBox check : Devices.selectedDevices)
```

I just want to be able to understand this and be a better developer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is called as [for-each](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html) (or) enhanced for loop in java.

It means for each JCheckbox in selectedDevices array (or) collection.

Comment: @Jigar Joshi: Thanks for editing, I am about to add same link.

Comment: More precisely, an array or `Iterable`

Comment: @steve kuo: iterable was the wording i was looking for. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

it is [For-Each](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html) loop it is same as

```
for (Iterator<JCheckBox> i = Devices.selectedDevices.iterator(); i.hasNext(); )
```

Example:

```
// Returns the sum of the elements of a
 int sum(int[] a) {
    int result = 0;
    for (int i : a)
        result += i;
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Copy each element of `Devices.selectedDevices`, in `JCheckBox check` and process.

It is read: `for each JCheckBox check in Devices.selectedDevices, do...`.